how to create a spark dataset of map of list<Row> from spark dataset<row>
I have a data set like this
input dataset
I need to make an another dataset of map of list from this dataset based on location
it will like this dataset<String, List>
where key will be values from location column
output map of list
System.out.println("reading user records");
Dataset<Row> user_df = MongoSpark.read(my_spark)
    .option("collection", "user")
    .option("readPreference.name", "secondaryPreferred")
    .load();

strLogMsg = "printing user_df records";
System.out.println(strLogMsg);
user_df.show(2);

strLogMsg = "creating user_df groups by location";
System.out.println(strLogMsg);

JavaPairRDD<String, Row> jpRDD = user_df.toJavaRDD().mapToPair(new PairFunction<Row, String, Row>() {
    public Tuple2<String, Row> call(Row row) throws Exception {
        return new Tuple2<String, Row>((String) row.getAs("location"), row);
    }
});

JavaPairRDD<String, Iterable<Row>> user_location_list = jpRDD.groupByKey();
strLogMsg = "printing user_location_list records count";
System.out.println(strLogMsg);
System.out.println(user_location_list.count());

upto this its working fine –
but how to get list of records for a location? –
here is datasets
input dataset
userid  username    location    
1       ram         karnataka   
2       shyam       rajasthan   
3       hemant      himachal    
4       raju        chitoor 
5       ravi        rajasthan   
6       titoo       himachal    
7       shukhi      chitoor 
8       raju        chennai 
        
        

output dataset<String, List>
user_location   userid  username    location
karnataka       1       ram         karnataka
            
rajasthan       2       shyam       rajasthan
                5       ravi        rajasthan
            
himachal        3       hemant      himachal
                6       titoo       himachal
            
chitoor         4       raju        chitoor
                7       shukhi      chitoor

i tried this but giving error
String[] arColNames = temp_df.columns();
String strCols ="";
for(String strcol : arColNames){
    if(strCols.isEmpty()){
        strCols = strcol;
    }else{
        strCols += ","+strcol;
    }
}
System.out.println("strCols - " + strCols);
Dataset<Row> user_by_location_ds = temp_df.groupBy("location").agg(functions.collect_list(functions.struct(strCols)).as("loc_list"));

giving this error
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: [UNRESOLVED_COLUMN.WITH_SUGGESTION] A column or function parameter with name....


Please don't post images of text/data. Instead, post these as text. Also, can you please include your attempt and show what exactly the issue is?

hi dan1st, just today i start using this site. let me know how to reply your comment

You can [edit] your questions and include all the information (in text form/using Markdown).  You can use Markdown tables if you want to. For code or similar, please use [code block]s.

I dont know how to put table and code. maybe i will comeback later

where i have to paste table format data

and where i have to put my code

JavaPairRDD<String, Iterable> key_list = jpRDD.groupByKey();
strLogMsg = "printing key_list records count";
System.out.println(strLogMsg);
System.out.println(key_list.count());

upto this its working fine

but how to get list of records for a location?

You can use the [edit] link below your question (or the one in this comment) for editing the question. There, you can paste all the necessary data inside the question (not in comments). Please make sure you are describing the exact problem you are facing (i.e. what you expect your code to do, why you think your code should do that and what it actually does/how that differs from your expectations. See also [mcve]. When editing the question, you also have formatting options available.

Do you want to get all records for a specific location or do you want all records grouped by location?

i need a dataset<String, List> i.e. like in java a map of list where key is location and list is all records for that location. so that i can add some more column from another department dataset to this dataset

Does Dataset#groupBy help?

i tried but dont know how to get list of rows for each location

and not able to print schema also

Does this answer your question? You should be able to use groupBy() followed by agg(collect_list("combined")) where combined is the column you want to have in the result.

no it did not  worked for me. i am trying some other way

What happens when doing that?

See I want all records grouped by location. so that next i fetch data for a location in loop and add some more column from other dataset. if you know the solution kindly help me. thanks for your attention

i updated with error which i got

I think you would need to pass a String[] to the struct() call. Also, it might be necessary to use withColumn as shown in the answer I linked.

i tried both cases its giving same error. while if i pass hard coded cols  (about 16 cols) names inside struct its working.

String[] is not accepting in struct

It looks like you need to pass the first one as a String and then supply the others as a String[] so essentially struct(firstColumn, arrayOfOtherColumns)

how to get first col name?

You have arColNames. Separate the first element out of it.

thanks now it worked for me as expected. but now MongoSpark.write gives out of memory issue on my local system with 16gb ram

hi, As i got the solution. how to close this question

You can answer your own question if you want to or we could close it as a duplicate of Collect rows as list with group by apache spark
